# Why do we still create an Activity object in a custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Am new to new to android development so please forgive me if this sounds stupid to you. Please why do we still create an activity object in a custom adapter for list view, when there's is parameter for a context object in the constructor. I am learning with a udemy course and thats what the teacher does.[This is a screenshot of what he did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIIU2.jpg)

Comment: Please paste code instead of images.

Comment: I dont have my pc with me. But u can see the screenshot

Comment: It's not Stack Overflow guidelines, questions and answers on SO are not only for solving immediate problems, but to also help future readers, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: You may need a `Context` parameter if you run a certain method inside the `Adapter` which may require the use of a context. For example: Showing a `Toast` message, accessing `SharedPreferences`, starting/stopping any `Service`, etc.

Comment: You'd never create an Activity.  The framework always does that for you.  Luckily you aren't creating one in the screenshot you shared.